# Auto-Renewable Subscriptions: Detecting Gaps

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an app for providing digital magazines and other periodicals. for integrating auto-renewable subscriptions and a lot of research, I came across the problem of detecting gaps in a subscription.

let's say a user subscribes for a month, opts out for half a year and subscribes again afterwards. using the apple-recommended server-based architecture for building audit trails and the whole receipt stuff, it would be pretty straightforward to track a user's subscription history. however, if there's no user-triggered transactional activity during the unsubscribed period, we will never receive an *expired* return value. as a consequence, the app will identify a valid subscription and unlock any content which was released when there was no actual subscription.

I'm not sure if I'm missing an important point, since I haven't found any helpful information on the web so far.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What about scheduling a cron job on a server, that will verify all current receipts once per day? Or maybe you found another working solution for that?